Need help about computing the limit of a series
Problem : Suppose $a_{n+1}=a_{n} + \frac{a_n^2}{n^2}$, and $ 0 \leq a_1 < 1 $.
Prove $lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ exists.
Here is my current solution, which only holds partially:
If $a_1 = 0$, then $a_n = 0$;
For $a_1 > 0$,
$a_{n+1} - a_{n} = \frac{a_n^2}{n^2} \geq  0$, $a_n$ increases monotonically.
So
$a_{n+1}=a_{n} + \frac{a_n^2}{n^2} \leq a_{n} + \frac{a_n \cdot a_{n+1}}{n^2}$, divide both sides by ${a_n \cdot a_{n+1}}$, we got $\frac{1}{a_n} - \frac{1}{a_{n+1}} \leq\frac{1}{n^2} $
We can sum both sides:
$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\frac{1}{a_i}-\frac{1}{a_{i+1}}) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i^2}$,
which means $\frac{1}{a_1} - \frac{1}{a_{n+1}}\leq\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i^2}$
When n approaches infinity, the right hand side approaches $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ (skip this proof)
which means $lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{a_{n+1}} \geq \frac{1}{a_1} - \frac{\pi^2}{6} $
Now here is the tricky part: For $\frac{1}{a_1} > \frac{\pi^2}{6}$, I can take the reciprocal of both sides,
and have $lim_{n\to\infty}{a_{n+1}} \leq \frac{1}{\frac{1}{a_1}-\frac{\pi^2}{6}}$, so the limit exists
However, if $1 < \frac{1}{a_1} \leq \frac{\pi^2}{6}$, I cannot do this. Then does the limit exists in this case? I write a code in MATLAB when $a_1 = \frac{6}{\pi^2}$ and run a very large loop, seems $a_n$ exists and is between 2.2 and 2.3.Is there a way to prove? Thanks.

This is a problem in this year's Alibaba math contest (final round).  So it is expected to be very difficult.

@Zhanxiong I came across this problem on Douyin (I'm not participating in this contest), and feel the problem seem to look easy. But it may be much harder than it looks.

That's fine.  The contest is over :).  Probably "Douyin" just copied this problem fro the contest.
